# Understanding MultiFileWordCount example in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to understand MultiFileWordCount example in order to implement CombineFileInputSplit in Hadoop.

Most of it is easy except for 2 lines which I'm finding to be very confusing

https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/MultiFileWordCount.java#L142

I'm not clear why is skipFirstLine needed and why offset is decreased by 1.

This is the same thing used in the [post by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-hadoopcombine/) as well. Some help here will be greatly appreciated.